# How to get random ids, that are not on X list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a code snippet that essentially finds a random List, and prints it out. However in the loop it also saves that id into a table called statuses.

Now I want to be able to go through that list again, and this time print out 150 randoms. However, this time I want it to check through statuses first to make sure that List item haven't been printed out before.

Here's the code I have now:

```
class ScheduleTweets
@queue = :schedules_queue

def self.perform(user_token, user_id)
client = Buffer::Client.new(user_token)
user = user_id
list = List.all.sample(150)
profiles = client.profiles
profile_ids = profiles.map(&:id)
list.each do |list|
  list.statuses.create(:user_id => user)
    client.create_update(body: {text: "#{list.text}", profile_ids: profile_ids })
  end
 end
end
```

If I were to guess I should add something after List.all.sample(150) where it checks if the list has a list_id that is present in Status.

Answer (score 0):

Gather the list items from the `statues` table and make an array with that result.

```
stat_ids = Status.all.collect{|s| s.list_id}
```

now loop through the random 150 list and check the list id contains in **stat_ids** or not.

```
random_lists.each do |rl|
  if stat_ids.include?(rl.id)
    //do something
  end
end
```

As I don't know your database architecture, I assumed it as above.